# How do I make BibLaTeX print postnotes and print a new bibliography entry for every citation with a different postnote?

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, citing, custom-bib

I have been making a Texas lawyer .bbx and .cbx, and, in doing that, I created a citation style called courtrule. For example, Rule 4 of the Texas Rules of Civil Procedure is cited like Tex. R. Civ. P. 4. However, because there are hundreds of different rules, I want to have a general `\cite{}` where I can pass the rule number as a postnote, i.e., `\cite[4]{TRCP}` will cause this:

In-text: Tex. R. Civ. P. 4

In-bibliography: Tex. R. Civ. P. 4

At the moment, when I write `\cite[4]{TRCP}`, it does the correct in-text citation, but it does not print the postnote in the bibliography. Additionally, I will cite multiple different rules, so I might have `\cite[500]{TRCP}` as well as `\cite[4]{TRCP}`. I want the bibliography to make a new entry for each different postnote. Is that possible?

This is my bibliography driver code now:

```
\DeclareBibliographyDriver{courtrule}{%
  \usebibmacro{begentry}%
  \printfield{title}\addspace\printfield{postnote}\hspace{-0.7ex}
 \dotfill\usebibmacro{pageref}%
}
```

But that just makes the bibliography print
`Tex. R. Civ. P.` without the number. [EDIT: I have learned it's because the `postnote` field is not available in the bibliography]

I know I'm doing it wrong, but I don't know how to do it right.

Comment: Welcome to tex.se.

Comment: In the manual (`texdoc biblatex`): "[Postnote is] The postnote argument passed to a citation command. This field is specific to citations and not available in the bibliography."

Comment: Tricky: Generally speaking, if you want separate bibliography entries, you need separate `.bib` entries.

Comment: It sounds as if you need (a) each rule to act as if it were its own standalone bibentry; or (b) accumulate the postnotes (excluding repeats, ibids and locits??) and print a custom list. A `crossref=` field for the rule  as a child entry (e.g. `trcp123,rule={TRCP123},crossref={trcp}`...) would point to, and inherit from, the parent entry (e.g., `trcp,title={Tex. R. Civ. P.}...`) and not need an actual postnote.

Comment: One way to accumulate is to use `gappto` (from etoolbox) to globally append to `\somemacro` during citation, and then print the contents of `\somemacro` at the end of the document. A custom expl3 command could also do this (plus sort and cleanup). What's your timeline/timeframe?

Comment: You could also us a dedicated index ("Table of Rules", say; to match with a Table of Cases, and Table of Statutes, both also indexes) when citing, which is how it is normally done in terms of document structure. The indexing mechanism would also take care of duplicates and sorting, as well.

Comment: @Cicada, I must have overlooked that bit in the documentation, thank you. I do use a table just for the rules, statutes, and cases, yes. It's one Table of Authorities with the authorities separated into their types.
I don't have a specific timeline, I am just doing this because it is interesting. If push comes to shove, I can manually enter everything in the bibliography. I do not have any pending cases where I need to use this at the moment. 
I do not 100% understand your comment about the `crossref=` field. I will check the documentation further.

Comment: But yes, I would like to accumulate the postnotes and exclude repeats. I will look into `gappto` as well.

Comment: @DarrisHawks Split indexing captures what you want, to produce a "table". Have a look at the answer (uses `splitindex` via `imakeidx`), see if it is close to your use-case.

Answer (score 2):

Index the citations.

[image: toa]

A quick, five-minute proof of concept using out-of-the-box Biblatex, the `title=` and `author=` fields for storing the authority and law report(s) respectively, and `\citetitle` and `\citeauthor` citation commands to retrieve that information.

Usage, for bibentry `X`:

```
\citetitle{X}, \citeauthor{X}\index[indexname]{\citetitle{X}, \citeauthor{X}}
```

With (numeric) pinpoint:

```
\citetitle{X}, \citeauthor[45]{X}\index[indexname]{\citetitle{X}, \citeauthor[45]{X}}
```

Tricky part with indexing is getting index sort keys right, and not unintentionally adding/removing blank spaces in the index entries when using different commands to add an (i.e., the same) item.

With alphanumeric pinpoints, the index sort key (and citation prefix) has to be added manually.

For example, to bring `r 45(a)` into the `rules` index/table (and into the citation in the text, if there is a citation):

```
\citetitle[r 45(a)]{tcpr}\index[rules]{r 045@\citetitle[r 45(a)]{tcpr}}
```

The MWE has some more details.

It is a multi-step process (see `Toolchain` in the MWE).

Remember to run with shell escape on.

MWE

```
%Toolchain:
%(pdf/xe/lua)latex with shell escape
%biber
%latex
%splitindex -s plainindexstyle.ist
%latex
%latex

\begin{filecontents*}[overwrite]{\jobname.bib}
@misc{tcpr,  %misc: just for demo
  title = {TCPR},
  pagination = {rule}, %bibstring to apply if postnote is digits
    }
@misc{auth1, 
  title = {A v B},
  author = {{4 LR 456}},
    }
@misc{auth2c, 
  title = {The Dog Co. v. The Cat Co.},
  author = {{4 LR 458}},
    }
@misc{auth3c, 
  title = {U.S. v. U.S.},
  author = {{102 U.S.X.C. 123}},
    }
    
\end{filecontents*}

%style file for index
\begin{filecontents*}{plainindexstyle.ist}
delim_0 "\\space\\dotfill\\space "
delim_1 "\\space\\dotfill\\space "
delim_2 "\\space\\dotfill\\space "
delim_n ", "
delim_r "--"
delim_t ""
encap_prefix "\\"
encap_infix "{"
encap_suffix "}"

\end{filecontents*}




\documentclass{article}
\newcommand\rulesep{\rule{0.4\textwidth}{.4pt}}
%------------------

\title{Creating a Table of Rules}
\author{}
\date{}


\usepackage[splitindex,noautomatic,nonewpage]{imakeidx}

\newcommand\abibname{authortitle}
\newcommand\abibstyle{style=\abibname}
\usepackage[
    \abibstyle , 
    indexing=cite,
    citetracker=true,
    ibidtracker=false,
    pagetracker=true,
%   idemtracker=true,
%   opcittracker=true,
%   loccittracker=true,
%   autocite=footnote,
%   datezeros=true,
        ]{biblatex}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
        
\NewBibliographyString{atparagraph,rule}        
\DefineBibliographyStrings{english}{%
atparagraph = {at para},
rule = {r},
}
%=================
%indexing


\newcommand\pagerefindexnote{\noindent\small\mdseries $\to$ References are to page numbers.}


\makeindex

\makeindex[name=rulesa,title=Table of TCP Rules,columns=3,columnseprule,intoc]
\makeindex[name=cases,title={\normalsize Cases},columns=1]
\makeindex[name=rules,title={\normalsize Rules},columns=1]




\usepackage[
                final=true,
                bookmarks,
            colorlinks=true,        
            allcolors = black,  
            citecolor=blue, 
            hyperindex=false,       
]{hyperref}



% variations instead of having \cite...\index... all the time
\newcommand{\icite}[1]{\cite[#1]{tcpr}\index[rulesa]{r~#1}}

\newcommand{\iicite}[2]{\cite[#1]{tcpr}\index[rulesa]{r~#2@r~#1}}

\newcommand{\iiicite}[3]{\cite[#1]{tcpr}\index[rulesa]{r~#3@r~#2{#1}}}

\newcommand{\ivcite}[4]{\cite[#1]{tcpr}\index[rulesa]{r~#3@r~#2{#1}|#4}}


\newcommand{\vcite}[2]{\cite[#1]{tcpr}\index[rulesa]{#2}}


%some wrapper commands for convenience
%%\imki@wrindexentry{names}{Charles}{26} - this is an imakeidx macro
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\addindexitem}[3]{%
\imki@wrindexentry{#1}{#2}{#3}}
\makeatother

\newcommand{\textformat}[1]{\textsf{\textbf{#1}}}

\newcommand\yq{\begin{quotation}}
\newcommand\yqq{\end{quotation}}

\newcommand\yc{\begin{center}}
\newcommand\ycc{\end{center}}

\newcommand\yi{\begin{itemize}}
\newcommand\yii{\end{itemize}}

\newcommand\yis{\item[\space]}

\newcommand\zzz[2]{\cite[#1]{tcpr}\index[rules]{r #2@\citetitle[#1]{tcpr}}}
%1=rule2=sortkey

%------------------
\begin{document}

\maketitle
\newpage
\tableofcontents
\newpage
\index{p} %seems general index is expected/assumed??
%\printindex

\indexprologue{\pagerefindexnote}

%\addindexitem{cases}{     @\textit{Case}|textit}{Page(s)}
%\addindexitem{rules}{     @\textit{Rule}|textit}{Page(s)}

\printindex[rulesa]

\newpage

Index the citations.

Use multiple indices, one for each category of authority.


\yc
\bfseries
TABLE OF AUTHORITIES
\ycc

\hfill\textbf{Page(s)}

\printindex[cases]

\printindex[rules]


\newpage
\section{Text}

\cite[4]{tcpr}\index[rulesa]{4}

xxx

\section{More Text}
xxx
\newpage
\cite[4]{tcpr}\index[rulesa]{4}

\cite[123]{tcpr}\index[rulesa]{123}

\iicite{5}{006}, \iicite{15}{015}, \iicite{52}{052}, \iicite{502}{502}, \iicite{12}{012}.

\cite[4556]{tcpr}\index[rulesa]{4556}

\iicite{53}{053}


\iiicite{14}{\textit}{014}

\iiicite{16}{\textbf}{016}


\iiicite{18}{}{018}{textbf}

\vcite{19}{r~019@r~19|textformat}

\vcite{19(a)}{r~019a@r~19!(a)} versus \vcite{r~19(a)}{r~019a@r~19!(a)}


\vcite{55(b)}{r~055b@r~55(b)|see{52(a)}}

\vcite{55(c)}{r~055c@r~55(c)!see{52(a)}}


\vcite{52(a)}{r~052a@r~52(a)}



\newpage

\vcite{52(a)}{r~052a@r~52(a)}

$\to$ \textbackslash index\{indexentry\}

An \verb.indexentry. is formatted as:

\yq
\yc
a@b|c
\ycc
where
\yi
\yis a = sortkey
\yis b = index display key(s), up to three levels
\yi
\item[·] level1!level2!level3
\yii
\yis c = page number format command name (without the backslash)
\yi
\item[·] can be \verb,see{...},
\yii
\yii
\yc
e.g., 052@52|textbf
\ycc

Sort the item as 052, print 52, and make the page number bold.

\textbf{References}: Do \verb.texdoc makeindex. to bring up both \verb,makeindex.pdf, and \verb,ind.pdf, manuals.
\yqq

\cite[457]{auth1}\index[cases]{\citetitle{auth1}, \citeauthor[457]{auth1}}


\cite[45]{tcpr}\index[rules]{r 045@\citetitle[45]{tcpr}}
\zzz{123}{123}
\zzz{200}{200}
\cite{auth2c}\index[cases]{\citetitle{auth2c}, \citeauthor{auth2c}}

\newpage
\cite{auth2c}\index[cases]{\citetitle{auth2c}, \citeauthor{auth2c}}
\cite{auth2c}\index[cases]{\citetitle{auth2c}, \citeauthor{auth2c}}
\cite{auth3c}\index[cases]{\citetitle{auth3c}, \citeauthor{auth3c}}
\zzz{123}{123}
\zzz{200}{200}
\zzz{201}{201}

\zzz{r 212(a)}{212(a)}
versus
\cite[r 212(a)]{tcpr}\index[rules]{r 212(a)@\citetitle [r 212(a)]{tcpr}}%note the space


\newpage

\cite{auth3c}\index[cases]{\citetitle{auth3c}, \citeauthor{auth3c}}
\zzz{123}{123}

\newpage
\cite{auth3c}\index[cases]{\citetitle{auth3c}, \citeauthor{auth3c}}
\zzz{85}{085}
\zzz{85}{085}

\newpage
\cite{auth2c}\index[cases]{\citetitle{auth2c}, \citeauthor{auth2c}}
\cite{auth3c}\index[cases]{\citetitle{auth3c}, \citeauthor{auth3c}}

\newpage
\cite{auth2c}\index[cases]{\citetitle{auth2c}, \citeauthor{auth2c}}
\zzz{123}{123}
\zzz{85}{085}

\citetitle[r 45(a)]{tcpr}\index[rules]{r 045@\citetitle[r 45(a)]{tcpr}}



\bigskip
\hfill\rulesep\hfill\ %\hrule%{0.8\linewidth}
\bigskip

%===============================================

\end{document}
```